# Parsing Stylus with gulp-usemin

Tags: gulp, stylus

I'm migrating some code from Less to Stylus.  In my code below, `gulp-usemin` compiles the Less files correctly, but I don't have it working with the Stylus files.

#### Source Files

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp    = require('gulp'),
    less    = require('gulp-less'),
    stylus  = require('gulp-stylus'),
    nib     = require('nib'),
    usemin  = require('gulp-usemin');

gulp.task('usemin', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/index.html')
    .pipe(usemin({
      less: [less()],
      stylus: [stylus({use: nib(), compress: false})]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

index.html

```
<!-- build:less css/less.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="foo.less">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bar.less">
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:stylus css/stylus.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="foo.styl">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bar.styl">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

foo.less

```
// This comment should disappear
html {
  margin: 0;
}
```

bar.less

```
body {
  background: #eee;
}
```

foo.styl

```
// This comment should disappear
html
  margin: 0
```

bar.styl

```
body
  background: #eee
```

#### Compiled Files

index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/less.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylus.css"/>
```

less.css

```
html {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background: #eee;
}
```

stylus.css

```
// This comment should disappear
html
  margin: 0
body
  background: #eee
```

As you can see, the Stylus files are concatenated, but not parsed at all.  Am I using `gulp-usemin` correctly?  Should I be using a different plugin?

Comment: Gulp-usemin is [blacklisted](https://github.com/gulpjs/plugins/blob/db6505106f12cc4546e73f8c0bf179e647641ecc/src/blackList.json#L33) on gulp plugins site. It is suggested to use gulp-useref instead.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the blacklist.  I've also tried 'gulp-useref` and I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

There has not been much activity on this post, so I'll go ahead and answer myself.

Rather than continue down this path, I discovered the wonderful world of [`gulp-inject`](https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject).  The Stylus files are now compiling properly with the following code, but the great side effect is how everything gets injected cleanly into the html.

#### Source Files

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My index</title>
  <!-- components:css -->
  <!-- bower installed css files will go here... -->
  <!-- endinject -->
  <!-- app:css -->
  <!-- built css files will go here... -->
  <!-- endinject -->
</head>
<body>
  <!-- components:js -->
  <!-- bower installed scripts will go here... -->
  <!-- endinject -->
  <!-- app:js -->
  <!-- app scripts will go here... -->
  <!-- endinject -->
</body>
</html>
```

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp    = require('gulp'),
    inject  = require('gulp-inject'),
    bower   = require('main-bower-files'),
    filter  = require('gulp-filter'),
    es      = require('event-stream'),
    stylus  = require('gulp-stylus'),
    concat  = require('gulp-concat'),

    cssFilter   = filter('**/*.css'),

    compileBower = function () {
      return gulp.src(bower())
                 .pipe(cssFilter)
                 .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/components/css'))
                 .pipe(cssFilter.restore());
    },

    compileStylus = function () {
      return gulp.src('./src/css/app.styl')
                 .pipe(stylus())
                 .pipe(concat('app.css'))
                 .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'));
    },

    compileJS = function () {
      return gulp.src('./src/app/**/*.js')
                 .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'));
    },

    injectIndex = function () {
      return gulp.src('./src/index.html')
                 .pipe(inject(compileBower(), {name: 'components'}))
                 .pipe(inject(es.merge(compileStylus(), compileJS()), {name: 'app'}))
                 .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'));
    };

gulp.task('build', injectIndex);
```

#### Sample Compiled File

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>MyApp</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/components/css/font-awesome.css"
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/components/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/app.css">
</head>
<body>
  <script src="/app/components/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="/app/components/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="/app/module/module.js"></script>
  <script src="/app/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/futurechan/gulp-asset-transform I think the beauty of the usemin type solution is you can develop without a compilation process.